# Outlook showing one our difference when using iCalendar with Timezone

Tags: outlook, icalendar, rfc5545

Following is the iCalendar that I am sending with the mail from my application

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Test Cal//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Kolkata
TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata
X-LIC-LOCATION:Asia/Kolkata
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+055328
TZOFFSETTO:+055320
TZNAME:HMT
DTSTART:18800101T000000
RDATE:18800101T000000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+055320
TZOFFSETTO:+0630
TZNAME:BURT
DTSTART:19411001T000000
RDATE:19411001T000000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0630
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
TZNAME:IST
DTSTART:19420515T000000
RDATE:19420515T000000
RDATE:19451015T000000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0630
TZNAME:IST
DTSTART:19420901T000000
RDATE:19420901T000000
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170323T084200Z
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20170401T083000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20170401T090000
SUMMARY:Test Summary
TZID:Asia/Kolkata
LOCATION:888-795-6545
UID:20170323T084200Z-1@fe80:0:0:0:0:100:7f:fffe%12
DESCRIPTION:Candidate Name:  Tess User\nContact Phone Number: 888-256-6522
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The actual time is 8:30 - 9:00

But when the calendar open in outlook it shows 7:30 - 8:00

Any problem with the `VCALENDAR` element
I have seen similar questions here but could not help.

Answer (score 0):

Your VTIMEZONE component doesn't have any definitions that effect the dates in your VEVENT.  They are all for the year 1942 and earlier.

Also, it doesn't make sense to put a TZID property in your VEVENT component.